# OpenGL with GLUT-- malloc errors

Tags: image, opengl, malloc, cimg

I want to screen scrape the image from a GLUT window that has been rendered in OpenGL. In side of the display callback I inserted this code:

```
display() {
        drawTriangle(); //Renders the image
        if(shouldDisplay) {
            shouldDisplay=0;
            bytes = width*height*3; //Color space is RGB
            buffer = (GLubyte *)malloc(bytes); //buffer is global var for now
                glFinish();
            glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

        }
        glutSwapBuffers();
    }
```

After this code runs, malloc starts failing. It fails with ENOMEM, error 12. I don't know enough about operating systems or GLUT to understand why this is happening. I'm only trying to allocate 17K on a machine with 3 GB. I'm using Windows XP and Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express. Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: What are the types of width,height, and bytes, how many times is the code run, and are you freeing the memory somewhere?

Comment: Good one.. no free() in sight :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code misses a `free(buffer)` at the end, so with each redraw more and more memory is consumed until the process runs out of memory and/or address space (the later only on a 32 bit  system, since 64 bits of address space are hardly to exhaust with small allocations in a reasonable time).

Comment: I found the missing free buffer in a debug session with a friend. That was causing the problem I described. Thanks for looking at it and I'm sorry for posting such a bone headed mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase this half-cocked answer. I think the heap is being trashed, perhaps by a *missing* free() and consecutive allocations perhaps by glReadPixels overwriting your target buffer.

Most framebuffers are at least 32-bit/dword aligned which suggests that, as the comment here says, w*h*4 bytes might just work as it matches the internal representation.

Setting the alignment to 1 byte (like another answer says) seems fine too to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try `glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` before calling glReadPixels.